# Problem with Magento 2.2.5 update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.2.5

i have a problem with the update of my magento installation from 2.2.3 to 2.2.5, when I try to make the composer update appear this error:
Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module ^2.0.4 -> satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module[2.0.12, 2.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

I have see that last version of amazon pay module is the 1.2.6.
How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change one line in root composer.json file from

```
magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.3"
```

to

```
 magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.5"
```

and run command

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Pay is bundled with Magento 2.2.4 onwards. If you already had Amazon Pay installed, you should remove it from your composer.json and use the version included with Magento.